# Intermittent Text Import Error (Error 9)

Tags: excel, vba, import

I am not sure if this is the right place for the question, but this is a little out of my knowledge base.

My issue is that I have a piece of code that simply imports a text document and uses a space delimiter. I have used this code many times on my terminal and it works. However when I run it on a some different terminal I get an error with it, other times its fine.

My code is:

Dim Ret

```
Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

If Ret <> False Then
    With Sheets("Primary").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & Ret, Destination:=Workbooks("Importer").Sheets("Primary").Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "Sample"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With
End If
```

I am getting a "Runtime Error 9: Subscript out of range" when I run this code. The debug menu selects this code for the issue:

With Sheets("Primary").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & Ret, Destination:=Workbooks("Importer").Sheets("Primary").Range("$A$1"))

I do not understand what causes this only on certain computer terminals. As far as I know all our Excel programs are setup the same.

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Runtime Error 9: Subscript out of range" is caused by invalid index/name given to an array.. say code `Sheets("Primary")` but there is no sheet named *Primary*..

Specific to the case, with given information, I suspect error happen because of name of workbook have been changed... So code `Workbooks("Importer")` try to look workbook named *Importer* and failed..

Comment: Thanks Susilo, I just don't understand why it can work on computer 1, 2 and 3 but when computer number 4 uses the program it fails. It is the same Excel document each time and all the sheet names have not changed. The workbook name hasn't changed either. I have placed it in a folder on our network and have accessed the same file from different terminals through other people's login and it just fails intermittently. I'm going to look into it a bit when I get to work today.

Comment: I look into it a bit today. All I needed to do was add (.xlsm) to the end of the workbook reference in the code and it all seems to work. Not sure why that is needed sometimes and others not. But it's good now. Thanks Susilo.